# jQuery click handler not working on IE from server, works in development

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

My handler for a button click is not working when I deploy my code to an IIS 7 server, but works fine in my development (VS2010) environment.  The problem only occurs on the server and with IE (IE 9).  If I go to the site with Chrome it works.  Also, clicks on other non-button controls like images work.

Here is the button declaration in html:

```
<button id="btnReleaseAssays" type="button">Release Assays</button>
```

Here is the jQuery `click` event handler:

```
    $('#btnReleaseAssays').click(function () {
```

This `click` handler does NOT work.

But if I change to the jQuery `on` handler shown below it does capture the event:

```
    $("#btnReleaseAssays").on("click", "", function () {
```

Any ideas on why this difference occurs?

Comment: Are you wrapping it in a document.ready function()?

Comment: Is your code inside the jQuery ready function? Eg, `$(function() { });`

Comment: try to change the event bind. Use the function "on", "bind" or "live" . These are other ways to deal with events . example: $(document).on('click', '#btnReleaseAssays',  function(event){ //your code here });